# How to work with maven dependency with different packaging

Tags: java, maven, osgi

Say I have a multi module maven project that builds components A and B.
Now I want to make a B a separate maven project but B has a dependency on A.
A also has a dependency on C. Because A has to be run in JAVA 7 and B has to be run on JAVA 8

C is a jar, but in C's pom the packaging is bundle.

```
<groupId>C</groupId>
<artifactId>C</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>bundle</bundle>
```

After building A, I'm building B.
I'm declaring A as a dependency in the pom with a correct version, and in the local repository, C.jar exist.

But when I try to build B,

```
mvn clean install
[ERRROR] Failed to execute on project B: Could not resolve dependencies for B.jar:1.0.0: Could not find artifact B:bundle:1.0.0 in <artifactory_url>
```

This worked perfectly when I had a parent pom and had them as modules
How can I just make the dependency in B, A, to pick up the jar file from the artifactory without using the pom?

Comment: You know that newer versions of Java can run code compiled for older versions?

Comment: Please include the part of B's pom.xml where you declare the dependency on A.